# Show media-frame-menu on custom Media Frame

Tags: multisite, images, uploads, admin-menu, media-modal

I have a plugin I built that adds a custom media frame with the following:

```
media_frame = wp.media.frames.media_frame = wp.media({
  title: 'Select your images',
  button: {
    text: 'Use Image'
  },
  multiple: false 
});
media_frame.open();
```

This produces a media frame that looks like this:
[image]

Thus far, this has been all I needed, but my site uses Wordpress Multisite and I'm trying to add in the [Network Shared Media](https://wordpress.org/plugins/network-shared-media/) plugin. However, Network Shared Media requires the media-frame-menu sidebar in order to access network images. I can see the sidebar when I click "Add Media"
[image]

What is required to add that sidebar to my custom menu? I've been looking around for hours, but haven't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone with a similar issue finds this post, [this solution worked for me](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94326/77792). Still have some kinks to work out with the specifics of my plugin, but this solution will at least add the sidebar menu to a custom modal.