# how to upload file to media library using link

Tags: media, media-library

In most cases I have images as links and I do extra work downloading them to my PC and then I have to upload them to wordpress website.
is there any plugins which enable you to upload file to media library from web directly?
edit:
I have this in drupal https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources
Is there such functionality in WP?

Comment: Hey Konstantin, plugin recommendation are off topic here. And you can find your answer to this by just googling.
Or searching this website: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50123/image-upload-from-url