# Find file url in post content and add it to media library

Tags: urls, media-library, pdf

I'm using the [Postie](http://postieplugin.com) plugin to receive an email to create a post. In that email there will be link(s) to a pdf. I'm using [wp_extract_urls](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_extract_urls) and code from this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50123/image-upload-from-url) to try to add the pdf to the media library and hopefully attach it to the post.

So far I'm able to add an entry to the media library, but it doesn't have any content. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

    $string = the_content();

    $urls = wp_extract_urls( $string );

    $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . $filename;

    $contents= file_get_contents($urls);
    $savefile = fopen($uploadfile, 'w');
    fwrite($savefile, $contents);
    fclose($savefile);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => $filename,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );

    $filenew = get_post( $attach_id );
    $fullsizepath = get_attached_file( $filenew->ID );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $fullsizepath );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    ?>
```