# How to make programmatic image upload generate thumbnail and sizes?

Tags: images, media, media-library, thumbnails

I have written a function to add a remotely-hosted image to the Media Library. It does so.

However, it does not generate a thumbnail in the Media Library - and I believe standard practice should also be to make up a range of image dimensions, too (?), which it does not.

```
$source_url = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/braincloud/image/fetch/c_thumb,g_face,w_275,h_275/https://contexthq.com/wp-content/uploads/promo329755877.png'
$filename = 'jana-eisenstein';
$img_title = 'Jana Eisenstein avatar';
```

.

```
  // cf. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50666/39300
  function add_remote_image_to_library($source_url, $filename, $img_title) {

    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    // ****** 1. Set folder and filename ****** //
    $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/avatars/' . $filename.'.'.pathinfo($source_url)['extension'];

    // ****** 2. Get the image ****** //
    $contents= file_get_contents($source_url);

    // ****** 3. Upload the image ****** //
    $savefile = fopen($uploadfile, 'w');
    fwrite($savefile, $contents);
    fclose($savefile);

    // ****** 4. Insert to Media Library ****** //
    // Insert
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => $img_title,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile);

    // Meta data
    $imagenew = get_post( $attach_id );
    $fullsizepath = get_attached_file( $imagenew->ID );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $fullsizepath );

    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

  }
```

The file gets added to the correct directory. However, in the Media Library, there is only a blank image icon...

[image]

Something is going on (or not) in the section `// Meta data`, where I feel it needs to be generating a thumbnail.

Note, I am not attaching this image to a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) to work properly in that it creates a thumbnail and other intermediate/image sizes like `medium` and `large`, the image attachment/post data must have the proper MIME type (`post_mime_type`), and despite you did set it in your `$attachment` array (the post data), there's a problem with this part in your code:

```php
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
```

where `$filename` was defined as `$filename = 'jana-eisenstein';` which is a file name *without* the extension (e.g. `.png`), and the value of that variable remained unchanged in your function, so with the above code, both `ext` and `type` in the `$wp_filetype` array are `false`.

Therefore, the `'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type']` is equivalent to `'post_mime_type' => false`, causing the image attachment to having invalid MIME type.

And to fix it, you can either pass the *full file path* to [`wp_check_filetype()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_filetype/), or use `basename( $uploadfile )` and not `basename( $filename )`:

```php
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $uploadfile, null ); // pass full path
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $uploadfile ), null ); // OR this works, too
```

### Alternate Option

This is based on [this example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_sideload/#comment-983) which uses `media_handle_sideload()` and automatically calls `wp_update_attachment_metadata()`, so you would not need to manually call it. :)

```php
function add_remote_image_to_library( $source_url, $filename, $img_title ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php'; // load media_handle_sideload()
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';  // load download_url()

    // Download the file to a temporary (system) file.
    $tmp = download_url( $source_url );

    // Build an array like in the $_FILES superglobal.
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $source_url ) );
    $file_array = array(
        'name'     => $filename . '.' . $wp_filetype['ext'],
        'tmp_name' => $tmp,
    );

    // Must manually delete the file in case of download errors.
    if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
        @unlink( $file_array[ 'tmp_name' ] );
        return $tmp;
    }

    // Now create the attachment plus thumbnails and other sizes.
    $post_id = 0; // the parent post ID, if applicable
    $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id, null, array(
        'post_title' => $img_title,
    ) );

    // You should delete the temporary file if the above resulted in a WP_Error.
    if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
        @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
        return $id;
    }

    return $id; // return the attachment ID or whatever that you want to return..
}
```

Comment: Sally, this looks veryhelpful. However, I'm setting an extension on line 8, `pathinfo($source_url)['extension']`. `wp_check_filetype()` confirms I have `ext` `string(3) "png"` and `type` `string(9) "image/png"`.

Comment: I'm actually saying you used `basename($filename)` which should be `basename($uploadfile)` or just pass `$uploadfile` alone as in the answer.

Comment: I see! Okay, changing to `basename( $uploadfile )` now results both in the Media Library thumbnail appearing and in two images being present - jana-eisenstein-170x150.png and jana-eisenstein.png. Double success, I think. Sally, this is a great answer and edit, possibly be the canonical answer on these questions - thanks. I will aim to try `media_handle_sideload()`, too. I don't see an 'alt' field amongst `post_mime_type`, `post_title`, `post_content` and `post_status`.

Comment: The `alt` text is saved as a private custom field named `_wp_attachment_image_alt`, so you can use `update_post_meta()` to update the `alt` text.